# mfpdev app preview returns below mentioned error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

> Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1051
>   Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->

stack trace

```
0   node                                0x0000000100bcb703 v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
1   node                                0x0000000100bc8889 V8_Fatal + 233
2   node                                0x00000001001473fa v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute) + 330
3   bufferutil.node                     0x00000001021f6d67 BufferUtil::Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object>) + 213
4   bufferutil.node                     0x00000001021f6c80 init(v8::Local<v8::Object>) + 42
5   node                                0x00000001009ce900 node::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 854
6   node                                0x000000010017bc9a v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) + 378
7   node                                0x00000001001dfb3c v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) + 924
8   node                                0x00000001001def79 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 281
9   ???                                 0x00001f07787063a7 0x0 + 34116945863591
10  ???                                 0x00001f0778bfd27a 0x0 + 34116951069306 Illegal instruction: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening due to an incompatibility with the Node.js 7 release. While this is investigated, as a workaround downgrade to the Node.js 6 release.

To keep track of this issue you can open a PMR (IBM support ticket). Or, wait until the next MobileFirst CLI release.